# I need a clarification about "character to be escaped is missing" exception

Tags: java, string

I have the following code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "${file.path}/fld/";
    String realValue = "C:\\path\\smtg\\";
    String variable = "${file.path}";
    path = path.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + variable.substring(2, variable.length() - 1) + "\\}", realValue);
    System.out.println(path);
    }
}
```

which gives me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:809)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:955)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
at testCode.Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

I already find some question about this problem, but still I don't understand this error. Can someone explain me what's going on?

I know that `replace` would work well, but unfortunately my collegues do not want to modify this code. So I need to know the exact problem to deliver a solution, because in other installations it works.

Comment: [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) expects a regular expression. Is there a reason you're not using [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)?

Comment: That's quite terrible... this code fragment wasn't created by me but now we have to install the application that contains this piece of code. Which works in other installations and I can't understand how it is possible.

Comment: Try  path = path.replace("${file.path}", realValue);

Comment: Problem with this solution is that `replaceAll` uses regex syntax not only in `replaceAll(target, ...)` but also in `replaceAll(..., replacement)` part where ``\`` is special character requiring escaping. If this code is supposed to replace literals, then using `replace` is correct choice. Also notice that `.` in regex means *any character* (exept line separators) so `file.path` will also match `fileApath` and `file1path` and so on. `replace` doesn't have this problem because it treats text literally, not as expression which needs to be interpreted/parsed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For your particular case you need to do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "${file.path}/fld/";
    String realValue = "C:\\\\path\\\\smtg\\\\";  //Notice the double slashes here
    String variable = "${file.path}";
    path = path.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + variable.substring(2, variable.length() - 1) + "\\}", realValue);
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

And now for the explanation. When you do a `replaceAll` the second part of a string is also interpreted by Java and has special characters like `\` and `$`. So in order to add a \ in the string you need to escape it and it becomes `\\` and if you want to use it in the resulting string literal you need to escape each one of them so it becomes `"\\\\"`

If you check java doc on the replaceAll method in a matcher:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

A simpler solution in your case would be to use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` since your pattern is pretty straightforward and you don't need a regex support, you can just match against a full string "${file.path}"

```
path = path.replace("${file.path}", realValue);
//or even
path = path.replace(variable, realValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

ReplaceAll is treating it's input as a regular expression. There are some valid escape expressions in regex, like `\w` for a word character or `\s` for any whitespace. If `file.path` is a Windows path containing `\` it may well have invalid escape sequences. Any any case it will not have the meaning you intend it to have.

The other occurrences that worked were they on a unix like environment? (unix, linux, os-x etc) if so it could of worked because those environments use `/` for path separators.

Before calling `replaceAll` you could try

```
variable = variable.replace("\\", "\\\\"); // to escape any \ in path.
```

Answer (score 0):

change the path String realValue = "C://path//smtg//" and try

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
String path = "${file.path}/fld/";
String realValue = "C://path//smtg//";
String variable = "${file.path}";
path = path.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + variable.substring(2, variable.length() - 1) + "\\}", realValue);
System.out.println(path);
}
}
```

Comment: You should use only one `/`, not double `//`!

Answer (score 0):

```
replaceAll(regexString, replacementString)
```

Rule #1:
   1st input accepts a regex, in your case, readability is less.

Rule #2: 
   2nd input accepts a string literal for replacement as it is, but as per `replaceAll` documentation, `$` or `\` characters in replacement string gives different result than expected, so this is causing`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing`.

Solution snippet:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String path = "${file.path}/fld/";
      String realValue = Matcher.quoteReplacement("C:\\path\\smtg");
      String variable = "\\$\\{file\\.path\\}";
      path = path.replaceAll(variable, realValue);
      System.out.println(path);
  }
}
```